# Attach file to email

Tags: excel, vba, email, office365, email-attachments

The first part of this code asks three questions that inputs into the workbook, then it takes a line of cells and copies it to a temp workbook. It then emails this temp workbook to a certain email address.

In the past it used Outlook on the local machine to mail the workbook. Outlook has been removed from the terminal server so it needs to be sent via relay server.

I updated the code and I can create the temp file, and generate the email.

How can I attach the temp file to the email?

```vb
Sub Mail_Week1_Maandag()

Dim userName As String
userName = InputBox("Aksie vir die dag?")
Range("'Data - Prod'!AD3").Value = userName
userName = InputBox("Hoeveel dissiplinêre vir die dag?")
Range("'Data - Prod'!AE3").Value = userName
userName = InputBox("Hoeveel bedankings vir die dag?")
Range("'Data - Prod'!AF3").Value = userName

Dim Email_Obj As Object
Dim Email_Configuration As Object
Dim Mail_Configuration As Variant
Dim Email_Sub As String
Dim Message_From As String
Dim Message_To As String
Dim Email_Cc As String
Dim Email_Bcc As String
Dim Message_Body As String
Dim AddAttachment As String

Dim Source As Range
Dim Dest As Workbook
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim TempFilePath As String
Dim TempFileName As String
Dim FileExtStr As String
Dim FileFormatNum As Long

Set Source = Nothing
On Error Resume Next
Set Source = Worksheets("Data - Prod").Range("B3:AF3").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
On Error GoTo 0

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set Dest = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)

Source.Copy
With Dest.Sheets(1)
.Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
.Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
.Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
.Cells(1).Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End With

TempFilePath = Environ$("temp") & "\"
TempFileName = wb.Name & " - Week 1 - Maandag"

If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = -4143
Else
FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 51
End If

Email_Sub = "PROD-OPSOMMING - " & wb.Name & " - Week 1 - Maandag"
Message_From = "email address"
Message_To = "email address"
Message_Body = "Sien aangeheg."
Set Email_Obj = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
On Error GoTo Error_Handling
Set Email_Configuration = CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")
Email_Configuration.Load -1
Set Mail_Configuration = Email_Configuration.Fields
With Mail_Configuration
.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = xxxxx
.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "xxxxx"
.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = xxxxx
.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = "xxxxx"
.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = xxxxx
.Update
End With

With Email_Obj
Set .Configuration = Email_Configuration
End With

With Dest
.SaveAs TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr, FileFormat:=FileFormatNum
On Error Resume Next

With Email_Obj
.Subject = Email_Sub
.From = Message_From
.To = Message_To
.TextBody = Message_Body
.CC = Email_Cc
.BCC = Email_Bcc
.AddAttachment Dest.FullName
.Send
End With

On Error GoTo 0
.Close savechanges:=False
End With

Kill TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr

Error_Handling:
If Err.Description <> "" Then MsgBox Err.Description

MsgBox "Week 1-Maandag se data suksesvol gestuur!"
End Sub
```

Comment: Use an intermediate variable ie `sTemp = TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr` and then you can close the workbook after saveAs and before attaching it with `.AddAttachment sTemp`,

Comment: Thank you!!!, updated the code and working as it should.

Comment: **Delete** the `On Error Resume Next` just before `With Email_Obj`. In **all** code with this structure usually `On Error Resume Next` just before `With OutMail` go ahead and **delete** the `On Error Resume Next`. You can debug the code. Use proper error handling if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

The [Workbook.FullName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.fullname) property returns the name of the object, including its path on disk, as a string. Make sure the returned string represents a valid file path on the disk. Otherwise, your need to use the same value used for the `SaveAs` method:

```
Dim filepath As String = TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr
```

Then you can re-use that string for both methods in the code - `SaveAs` and `AddAttachment`:

```
With Email_Obj
.Subject = Email_Sub
.From = Message_From
.To = Message_To
.TextBody = Message_Body
.CC = Email_Cc
.BCC = Email_Bcc
.AddAttachment filepath
.Send
End With
```

Finally, be aware that CDO was deprecated and not recommended for using now. Read more about that in the [Collaboration Data Objects (CDO) 1.2.1 is not supported with Outlook 2010 and later versions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/troubleshoot/development/collaboration-data-objects-1-2-1-not-supported-in-outlook-2010-and-later) article. You may consider using EWS or [Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-mail-concept-overview) instead.